# How to make sure that I am working with the most recent version of a file?

Tags: command-line, network-drive

I am using via ssh a remote computer which has a network drive. The problem is, that the network drive is so slow (perhaps, in part because of RAID), that if I create (or modify) rather large files (>1GB), then the changes are not immediately visible.

For example, I `wc -l testfile.txt` which reports (correctly) me 100.000 lines. Then I append a single line to this file. Then, after calling `wc -l testfile.txt` again it *still* reports 100.000 lines. But after several seconds executing `wc -l testfile.txt` will report 100.001 lines. This behavior confused me more than once earlier, and I am annoyed to the point, that I am asking for help.

Is there a command in Ubuntu, which reports whether a file I see is "the latest" (and not currently being written on, etc.)? How can I rest assured, that there are no pending IO operations with respect to a file in the background?

Comment: How are you appending to the file?

Comment: @heemayl valid question, but I speculate that it is irrelevant. I experience the same kind of behavior once I open a short makefile/.cpp file in nano, make some small changes, *save* them, and then executing `make all` will report that "no changes have been made". But then, minutes later it will run, and recompile the source. To answer your question: I am running a C code and I have no idea how it appends lines to a file. After the code is executed, and I get back the shell prompt, counting lines in the output file returns incorrect data, because network-synchronization have not happened yet.

Comment: How is the network drive mounted to your remote computer? NFS? iSCSI? Something else?

Comment: Also, specifically for the command you ask for, check the `sync` command.

Comment: Posting as a comment because this is incomplete but the `stat` command will give you very precise modify or change times to compare. You might try chaining two commands together so that you get visual feedback once both run, for example if you were editing the file in nano try `nano testfile.text && echo "done"`. When you see "done" in Terminal you know both commands successfully ran.